# how to avoid destructuring-bind ARG-COUNT-ERROR?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I need to read a string of Common Lisp object from database. The object should be a list with two elements of double-float; "(1.0d0 2.0d0)" for example:

```
(let* ((str "(1d0 2d0)")
       (off (read-from-string str)))
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
      off (list x y)))
```

But there are conditions that the string is not properly formatted? For example, the query failed, or the object doesn't exist. The code will give arg-count-error:

```
error while parsing arguments to DESTRUCTURING-BIND:
  too few elements in
    ()
  to satisfy lambda list
    (X Y):
  exactly 2 expected, but got 0
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL::ARG-COUNT-ERROR]
```

I have to use the following code to do type-check.

```
(let* ((str "(1d0 2d0)")
       (off (read-from-string str)))
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
      (if (and off
               (typep off 'list)
               (= 2 (length off)))
          off
          (list 0d0 0d0)) (list x y)))
```

The code snippet will return the default value if the str is not properly formatted. : **(0.0d0 0.0d0)**;

Am I doing it right?
Is there an better way to avoid this error?

Comment: Just a reminder: if you use the reader to read data, then it might be useful to bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. One option would be to use a pattern matching library (such as [Trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia)).

```
(defun read-coord (string)
  (match (read-from-string string nil)
    ((list x y) (list x y))
    (_ (list 0d0 0d0))))

CL-USER> (read-coord "(1d0 2d0)")
(1.0d0 2.0d0)
CL-USER> (read-coord "(1d0)")
(0.0d0 0.0d0)
CL-USER> (read-coord "")
(0.0d0 0.0d0)
```

If you want to check that `X` and `Y` are floats, you can add a guard pattern

```
(defun read-coord (string)
  (match (read-from-string string nil)
    ((list (guard x (floatp x))
           (guard y (floatp y)))
     (list x y))
    (_ (list 0d0 0d0))))
```

As pointed out by Rainer Joswig in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41164058/5747548), `READ-FROM-STRING` can cause other errors and `*READ-EVAL*` should be set to `NIL` when reading.

```
(defun safely-read-from-string (string)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
    (ignore-errors (read-from-string string))))

(defun read-coord (string)
  (match (safely-read-from-string string)
    ((list (guard x (floatp x))
           (guard y (floatp y)))
     (list x y))
    (_ (list 0d0 0d0))))
```

Also remember that you can use lambda list keywords, such as `&OPTIONAL`, with `DESTRUCTURING-BIND`. Using [Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) for the `ENSURE-LIST`-function, you could write

```
(defun read-coord (string)
  (destructuring-bind (&optional (x 0d0) (y 0d0) &rest _)
      (ensure-list (safely-read-from-string string))
    (declare (ignore _))
    (list x y)))

CL-USER> (read-coord "(1d0 2d0)")
(1.0d0 2.0d0)
CL-USER> (read-coord "(1d0)")
(1.0d0 0.0d0)
CL-USER> (read-coord "")
(0.0d0 0.0d0)
```

If you don't want to use any libraries, you can just check that a list is given yourself

```
(defun read-coord (string)
  (let ((coord (safely-read-from-string string)))
    (destructuring-bind (&optional (x 0d0) (y 0d0) &rest _)
        (if (listp coord)
            coord
            (list coord))
      (declare (ignore _))
      (list x y))))
```

Answer (score 4):

I am relatively new to lisp, so you better wait for the old dogs to give you their solution. Here is how I would refactor it.

For starters you can also check if both elements of a list are of type floats with

```
(floatp element)
```

This will make your snippet look like this

```
(let* ((str "(1d0 2d0)")
       (off (read-from-string str)))
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
    (if (and off
             (typep off 'list)
             (= 2 (length off)
             (every #'floatp off)) ; here is the new code
        off
        (list 0d0 0d0)) (list x y)))
```

However it is quite hard on the eyes already. Let's make it a predicate. I will assume that what you want is a coordinate. You will make the variable name match your application domain.

```
(defun coord-p (coord)
  (and coord
       (typep coord 'list)
       (= 2 (length coord)
       (every #'floatp coord)))
```

Now the snippet should look like this:

```
(let* ((str "(1d0 2d0)")
       (coord (read-from-string str)))
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
    (if (coord-p coord)
        coord
        (list 0d0 0d0))
    (list x y)))
```

Let's simplify the check inside the `destucturing-bind`

```
(defun ensure-coord (coord)
   (if (coord-p coord)
       coord
       (list 0d0 0d0)))
```

Now the snippet should look like this:

```
(let* ((str "(1d0 2d0)")
       (coord (read-from-string str)))
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
      (ensure-coord coord)
    (list x y)))
```

Now let's put the snippet inside a function:

```
(defun coord-from-string (str)
  (destructuring-bind (x y)
      (ensure-coord
       (read-from-string str))
    (list x y)))
```

This looks quite alright to me. But actually... why do we need the `destructuring-bind` again? It is completely useless by now:

```
(defun coord-from-string (str)
  (ensure-coord
    (read-from-string str))
```

**Bonus tip**: Use `defstruct` with `(:type list)`.

For further clarity and expressiveness you can declare a defstruct for your object. E.g.:

```
(defstruct (coord (:type list))
   (x 0d0 :type double-float)
   (y 0d0 :type double-float))
```

This way every **list** of two elements can be operated with the function provided from Common Lisp for operation of structs. E.g.:

```
(coord-y '(1d0 2d0)) ; => 2.0d0
```

Note the `(:type list)` in the declaration. This is why we can use a simple list to act as a struct. This way we can combine the versatility of lists with the functionality and expressiveness of structs. For example if you follow this tip the `ensure-coord` function will look like this:

```
(defun ensure-coord (coord)
  (if (coord-p coord)
      coord
      (make-coord)))
```

Arguably, the intentions are clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are many sources of possible errors. For example the reader could detect errors.

Make sure that you handle errors:

```
(defun get-it (s)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))      ; don't execute code on reading!
    (flet ((check (it)
             (if (and (listp it)
                      (= (length it) 2)
                      (every #'double-float-p it))
                 it
               (error "data is not a list of two double-floats: ~a" it))))
             (handler-case (check (read-from-string s))
               (error (condition)
                 (princ condition)
                 (list 0.0d0 0.0d0))))))


CL-USER 34 > (get-it "(0.0d0 0.0d0)")
(0.0D0 0.0D0)

CL-USER 35 > (get-it "(0.0d0 0.0d0")
End of file while reading stream #<SYSTEM::STRING-INPUT-STREAM 40E06AD7DB>.
(0.0D0 0.0D0)

CL-USER 36 > (get-it "(0.0d0 foo:aa))")
Reader cannot find package FOO.
(0.0D0 0.0D0)

CL-USER 37 > (get-it ")")
Unmatched right parenthesis.
(0.0D0 0.0D0)

CL-USER 38 > (get-it "(1 2 3)")
data not a list of two double-floats: (1 2 3)
(0.0D0 0.0D0)
```